# Changing install directory of python after installation

Tags: python-3, raspbian-buster, raspbian-lite

I have a fresh installation of Raspbian Lite. This one comes with Python 2.7 and 3.7 and no pip installed. I wanted to install Python 3.9.1 and followed the instructions [from here](https://installvirtual.com/how-to-install-python-3-8-on-raspberry-pi-raspbian/).

To briefly state the steps given there: Install dependencies, extract Python from the downloaded archive, `./configure --enable-optimizations`, `make` and `make altinstall`.

After completing the installation I realised that Python was installed in `/usr/local/bin/python3.9` and pip is installed in `usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip`. While the other Python installations are in `/usr/bin/`.

1. Can I (Should I?) somehow have it installed in `/usr/bin/`?
2. In the future if I want to install Python and pip in `/usr/bin/` what should I change in the above set of commands? I remember seeing in an tutorial article(that I am unable to find now) that they pass additional arguments to `./configure` that seemed like specifying the directory to install python in.
3. Now that it is installed there, I can directly set alias in `.bashrc` for `python3.9` and `pip3.9` as `python` and `pip`, right?

Comment: If you choose to install 3.9 you should use the default (correct) directory. There is no need to fiddle with `.bashrc` - progams installed in `/usr/local/bin` will run in preference to `/usr/bin`. You could run specific versions with python3.9 or python3.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No. Do not install it in `/usr/bin`. `/usr/bin` is for programs installed by the package manager. If you install packages manually, they go in `/usr/local/bin` (or `~/.local/bin` etc.).
2. You can use the `--prefix` option of the `configure` script to select the folder to install it to, by default the prefix is `/usr/local`. As mentioned in (1), don't set it to `/usr` or you'll break things.
3. Yes.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. After adding these two to `.bashrc` I updated pip using `python3.9 -m pip install --upgrade pip`. It showed a small message saying "Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writable". This is normal, right? After this pip is installed in `~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages` while `setuptools` is in `/usr/local/lib/...`. It seems now all new packages install to `~/.local/lib/...`

Comment: 3. NO! Setting an alias to `python` is a bad idea, because there are still (old?) programs that expect python2 with that. These programs may fail. The best is, always to call `python3`.